# Access properties of optional object/struct/variable inside parent struct

Tags: rust

I am not sure why I cannot access any field on my Vector... that Vector is an optional property (that now exists) of my dinner variable:

```rust
struct Dinner {
    name: String,
    dishes: Option<Vec<Dishes>>
}

let mut dinner = Dinner::new();
dinner.dishes = Option::from(dinner.get_dishes());

for dish in dinner.dishes {
    dish.temperature = Some("HOT");
}

println!("{:#?}", script);
```

```
error[E0609]: no field `temperature` on type `Vec<Dishes>`
  --> src/main.rs:14:21
   |
14 |                      dish.temperature = Some("HOT");
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^ unknown field
```

Update:

I just found out that when looping through the dishes

```
for dish in dinner.dishes {
    println!("{:#?}", dish)
}
```

There is only one entry, and that contains all my dishes... this is a Some(**all my dishes are in here**) and I need to access the content of that Some, I basically need to get rid of that `Some()` that wraps around the data I need to access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Note: I refer to your struct as `Dish` here, not `Dishes`, as the latter just makes this post grammatically difficult to parse)

An `Option<Vec<Dish>>` is *not* a `Vec<Dish>`. Even an `Option<Vec<Dish>>` that *has a value* is not a `Vec<Dish>`. There's no subtyping relationship here. An `Option<Vec<Dish>>` can be thought of as a *container* of zero or one dishes. In the same vein, an array of `Dish` is not, itself, a `Dish`. Even if the array happened to contain only one `Dish`, it would not be accurate to say that the array is, itself, a `Dish`.

```
for dish in dinner.dishes {
  ...
}
```

This is *not* iterating over a vector. This is iterating over an `Option`, which is a container of at most one vector. So the type of `dish` is `Vec<Dish>`, which does not have a `temperature`. If you know the optional value is nonempty, you can use [`Option::unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap) to get at the inner value

```
for dish in dinner.dishes.unwrap() {
  ...
}
```

This will panic if your assertion turns out to be wrong. But the more correct solution would be to build up the vector and *then* assign it to the field as a final step.

```
// Type annotations included for didactic purposes;
// they are not necessary in production code.
let mut dinner: Dinner = Dinner::new();
let mut dishes: Vec<Dish> = Vec::new();

for dish in dishes {
    dish.temperature = Some("HOT");
}

dinner.dishes = Some(dishes);
```

Comment: I absolutely love detailed explanations like this... thank you so much for your time and effort. Now my code works and I understand why id did not before.

Comment: You're very welcome! As a general rule, when I'm working in a language with a powerful type system like Rust, if something goes wrong, my first instinct is to add type annotations. Keep annotating local variables, and at some point Rust will challenge your assertion, and you'll know that that's where something went wrong. That strategy can also work for lifetimes.

Comment: It is worth noting there is a clippy lint against iterating over `Option`: [`clippy::for_loops_over_fallibles`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#for_loops_over_fallibles).

Comment: @SilvioMayolo note that with a proper IDE setup, you can also see the type computed by the in a blink of an eye, which provides tighter feedback than having to type half of the variables of your function when it bugs.